# Origin of the military term "technical" referring to weaponized pickup trucks

Tags: terminology

When did the term "technical" come to denote a converted pickup truck with an added weapon mount in military jargon?

Comment: It must be fairly recent. Can you cite a credible source using this term and edit it in please? According to Wikipedia, it dates to 1990 in Somalia.

Comment: @Cascabel - Note that "fairly recent" is 25 years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [counterinsurgency expert David Kilcullen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Kilcullen), as quoted in an article in *Newsweek*, the term originated in the 1990's in Somalia.

> Indeed, Africa, says Kilcullen, is where the truck got its nickname as a fighting vehicle, “the technical.” “When [nongovernmental organizations] and the U.N. first went into Somalia,” he says, referring to a period in the 1990s, “they were not able to bring their own guards. So **they got so-called ‘technical assistance grants’ to hire guards and drivers on the ground.** Over time, **a ‘technical’ came to mean a vehicle owned by a guard company,** and then eventually to mean a Hilux with a heavy weapon mounted on the back.”

- [*Newsweek*, Ravi Somaiya, "Why rebel groups love the Toyota Hilux,"](http://www.newsweek.com/why-rebel-groups-love-toyota-hilux-74195) Oct. 2010.

Answer (score 1):

The term's been around since the Somali civil war during the 90s.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_(vehicle)) bears this out:

> The term *technical* describing such a vehicle originated in Somalia in
>   the early 1990s. Barred from bringing in private security,
>   non-governmental organizations hired local gunmen to protect their
>   personnel, using money defined as "technical assistance grants".
>   Eventually the term broadened to include any vehicle carrying armed
>   men.[1] Technicals have also been referred to as battlewagons,
>   gunwagons,[2] or gunships.